# Naviagtion Drawer con Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, navigation-drawer

buenas noches.

Estoy intentando crear un Navigation Drawer en una app Android desarrollada con Kotlin.
Para ello, me estoy guiando del código de ejemplo que aparece en Material Design.

En el Activity Main tengo:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.AppBarLayout.PrimarySurface"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/logolqs" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/astrud"
                    android:text="S.A.Té.Li.Te."
                    android:textSize="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    />

                <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                    android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/iconomenu16"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:elevation="0dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_principal"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_menu_principal"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Ejecuto la aplicación y el menú está oculto.
Cuando deslizo el dedo desde el lateral, el menú se muestra perfectamente.

Ahora lo que quiero es que el menú se muestre al pulsar el botón <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar/>

En el MainActivity.Kt tengo esto ya que es lo que según la página de Materíal Design hay que poner.

```
    topAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener {
        drawerLayout.open() }
```

El problema que tengo es que el "Open" de las 2 líneas anteriores me lo marca en rojo.
Yo creo que la sentencia puede estar incompleta y me faltan parámetros o algo así.

Ahora bien, si yo pongo esto:

```
    topAppBar.setNavigationOnClickListener { 
        Toast.makeText( this, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() }
```

Al pulsar el botón del menú me muestra el mensaje.
Por lo tanto el botón sí funciona, lo que pasa es que no sé como decirle que lo que tiene que hacer el botón es mostrar el menú.

Estoy empezando con Kotlin
a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

saludos y muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, no es muy clara tu pregunta, el problema es que drawerLayout.open() lo marca en rojo pero deberías de agregar en las preguntas que es lo que necesitas realizar.

Comment: Al final lo he conseguido utilizando el método "openDrawer"

drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START).

Answer (score 1):

Al final lo he conseguido utilizando el método "openDrawer"

`drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START)`

Por si a alguien lo necesita...